# creating a map for storing structure coordinate as key and line number as the value

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have two structures. One for storing a point in 2D coordinate system:

```
struct Coordinate {
int x, y;
Coordinate() {};
Coordinate(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {};
} cr;
```

Another for storing the Coordinate and column number along with it.

```
struct BlobInformation {
Coordinate point;
int PixelValues[6];
int line;
int column;
char value;
} bi;
```

I'm trying to create a map which stores Coordinate as the Key and BlobInformation contents as the value.

When I try to insert the key, value pair it gives me the following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2678   binary '<': no operator found which takes a left-hand        operand of type 'const Coordinate' (or there is no acceptable conversion)  braille_obr c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xstddef  240
```

Comment: Please read your question and ask yourself "Could I answer that?"

Comment: `Coordinate` must implement an overload for `operator<()` or you need to specify an appropriate function for the [`Compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) template parameter.

Answer (score 0):

`std::map` is a sorted container, i.e. it sorts its keys with the `<` operator. `Coordinate` didn't implement one, that's why you are seeing this error. You can implement it (`bool operator<(const Coordinate& rhs);`, or use a `std::unordered_map`, which doesn't sort its keys.